# Find the response with the most words

Tags: r

Trying to find the respondent in the list g.list with the most words in their response (g.list is a list of respondents with their IDs). However, g.list contains lists within it with the actual response which leads to the lapply(length) giving length 1. I'm struggling to deal with this. I'd ideally like to do this using the lapply() and strsplit() functions.
Here's my code:

```
head(g.list)
```

Output:

```
$`1590553444`
[1] "Nothing"

$`1590610566`
[1] "Couldn't sit in a lot of them"

$`1590609253`
[1] "N/a"
```

Code:

```
g.split <- lapply(unlist(g.list), strsplit, " ")
head(g.split)
```

Output:

```
$`1590553444`
$`1590553444`[[1]]
[1] "Nothing"


$`1590610566`
$`1590610566`[[1]]
[1] "Couldn't" "sit"      "in"       "a"        "lot"      "of"       "them"    


$`1590609253`
$`1590609253`[[1]]
[1] "N/a"
```

Code:

```
 g.count <- lapply(unlist(g.split), length)
 head(g.count)
```

Output:

```
$`1590553444`
[1] 1

$`1590610566`
[1] 1

$`1590609253`
[1] 1
```

Code:

```
max(unlist(g.count))
```

I was expecting g.count <- lapply(unlist(g.split), length) to give the number of words. However, all of them are 1.

Comment: Can you also add the original `g.list` to your question?

Comment: Added original list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was where to place the `[[1]]`. `strsplit()` returns a list, hence why `length` was returned as 1.

```
# create data
g.list = list(
    `1590553444` = "Nothing",
    `1590610566` = "Couldn't sit in a lot of them",
    `1590609253` = "N/a"
)

# solution
get_len = function(string) {
    length(strsplit(string, " ")[[1]])
}

lapply(g.list, get_len)
```

---

```
$`1590553444`
[1] 1

$`1590610566`
[1] 7

$`1590609253`
[1] 1
```

To get the max:

```
max(unlist(lengths))
```

---

```
[1] 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Didn't consider creating a function for this since it didn't seem needed initially.

Comment: I find that I mostly write functions out of readability, it also makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

If we have only one entry per `list` element, `unlist`, then `strsplit` the `vector` which returns a `list` of vectors and then use `lengths`

```
out <- lengths(strsplit(unlist(g.list), " "))
out
1590553444 1590610566 1590609253 
         1          7          1
```

Then use `which.max` to get the index and extract the element with the max count

```
g.list[which.max(out)]
$`1590610566`
[1] "Couldn't sit in a lot of them"
```

---

Or another option is with `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(g.list, "\\S+")
[1] 1 7 1
```

#### data

```
g.list <- list(`1590553444` = "Nothing", 
  `1590610566` = "Couldn't sit in a lot of them", 
    `1590609253` = "N/a")
```